# observing erratic behavior while downloading(get) the file using socket

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I have implemented the mget command using socket. But the output i am getting is having some random behavior. Sometime i am able to download the whole file on client, sometimes i am able to download files partially,  sometime server code gives segmentation fault and sometimes client goes into infinite loop.

Server Code:

```
      /* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
//     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     /*bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");*/

     char command[512];
     bzero(command, 512);

    char buffer[4096];
     char output[5000];
     char f_size[20];

     int send_bytes;
     int written_bytes;
     int total_sent_bytes = 0;

     long int file_size;

     n = recv(newsockfd, command, 512, 0);  //try with MSG_WAITALL
     if(n < 0)error("Error receiving command");
     puts(command); //only file name

     FILE * fp;
     fp = fopen(command, "rb");
     if(fp == NULL)error("Can not open requested file");

     FILE * test_file_fp;
     test_file_fp = fopen("test_file.txt", "wb");
     if(test_file_fp == NULL)error("Can not open test file");

     fseek(fp,0, SEEK_END);
     file_size = ftell(fp);
     rewind(fp);

     sprintf(f_size,"%ld", file_size);

     send(newsockfd, f_size, strlen(f_size), 0);

     while(!feof(fp)){
         bzero(buffer, 4096);

         n = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 4095, fp);
         sprintf(output, "read bytes using fread = %d", n);
         puts(output);

         send_bytes = send(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1, MSG_MORE);
         total_sent_bytes += send_bytes;
         sprintf(output, "sent bytes using send = %d", send_bytes);
         puts(output);

         written_bytes = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), test_file_fp);
         sprintf(output, "written bytes using fwrite = %d", written_bytes);
         puts(output);

        //bzero(command, 512);

        //recv(newsockfd, buffer, 512, 0);

        puts("\n");
     }

     sprintf(output, "total sent bytes using send = %d\n", total_sent_bytes);
     puts(output);

     send(newsockfd, NULL, 1, 0);

     fclose(test_file_fp);
     fclose(fp);
     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

Client Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    int i;
//    char buffer[5000];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");


    char command[512];
    char output[5096];

    int send_command_bytes;
    int reveived_bytes;
    char buffer[4096];

    long int total_bytes;
    long int total_received_bytes;

    int written_bytes;

    sprintf(output, "IP Protocol Number = %d", IPPROTO_TCP);
     puts(output);

    FILE * fp;

    fp = fopen("received_file.txt", "wb");
    if(fp == NULL)error("Could not open file for receiving data");

    memcpy(command, "send_me.txt", 11); 

    send_command_bytes = send(sockfd, command, strlen(command), 0);
    puts(command);

    recv(sockfd, buffer, 4096, 0);
    total_bytes = atoi(buffer);

    sprintf(output, "Total bytes to be received = %ld", total_bytes);
    puts(output);

    total_received_bytes = 0;

    while(totala_received_bytes < total_bytes){
        bzero(buffer, 4096);
        reveived_bytes = recv(sockfd, buffer, 4095, 0); //try with MSG_WAITALL, MSG_DONTWAIT
        total_received_bytes += reveived_bytes;
        sprintf(output, "Number of bytes received = %d", reveived_bytes);
        puts(output);

        written_bytes = fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(buffer), fp);
        sprintf(output, "Total written bytes = %d", written_bytes);
        puts(output);

        //send(sockfd, "1", 2, 0);

        sprintf(output, "total Number of bytes received so far = %ld", total_received_bytes);
        puts(output);
        puts("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

From client i am sending the file name "send_me.txt" which needs to be downloaded and this filename is being read by server in a buffer named command. This file is being opened in server and then read and then sent to client.
I have tried many possibilities to overcome this issue but the issue still persists.

Comment: Learn [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your code has both of the common problems when dealing with communications over sockets

**1. Lack of NUL Termination**
Strings in C are `NUL` terminated, so either you need to send the `NUL` as part of the message, or you need to add the `NUL` on the receive side.

**2. Assumptions about message sizes**
It's a common misconception in socket programming that each `recv` will match the corresponding `send`. For example, if I `send` 10 bytes, followed by 50 bytes, and later 20 bytes, then the expectation is that `recv` will need to be called three times, and will return 10 bytes, 50 bytes, and 20 bytes. That is completely, utterly, totally wrong. In fact, the first `recv` will return anywhere from 1 byte to 80 bytes. That is, it may return any portion of the data from the first `send`, up to all of the data from all of the `sends`.

**Example from your code**
In the server code, you do this

```
 sprintf(f_size,"%ld", file_size);
 send(newsockfd, f_size, strlen(f_size), 0);
```

If the `file_size` is 123, then the sprintf will write `1`, `2`, `3`, `\0` to `f_size`, i.e. three digits and a NUL terminator. The strlen will return 3, so the code only sends the three digits but doesn't send the NUL terminator.

On the client side, you have this

```
recv(sockfd, buffer, 4096, 0);
total_bytes = atoi(buffer);
```

Since the server doesn't send the NUL byte and the client doesn't add the NUL byte, the `atoi` will see whatever the `recv` put in the `buffer`, followed by garbage. If you're lucky, the first garbage character won't be a digit, and `atoi` will work correctly. If you're unlucky the first garbage character will be a digit.

In addition to the missing NUL, the `recv` may only get 1 byte, in which case the file size is 1 (assuming the first garbage character is not a digit). Or the `recv` may get 100 bytes (the 3 byte length plus some of the bytes from the file). If the file happens to start with digits, the size will be wrong.

**Fixing the code**
On the server side, send the file size as a fixed length message with the NUL included, e.g.

```
#define MSGLEN 24
char buffer[MSGLEN];
snprintf( buffer, MSGLEN, "%*ld", MSGLEN-1, file_size );
send( sockfd, buffer, MSGLEN, 0 );
```

On the client side, read in a loop until you have all of the bytes for the size, but no more

```
#define MSGLEN 24
char buffer[MSGLEN];
int count = 0;
int index;
for ( index = 0; index < MSGLEN; index += count )
{
    count = recv( sockfd, &buffer[index], MSGLEN - index, 0 );
    if ( count <= 0 )
        break;
}
if ( index != MSGLEN || buffer[MSGLEN-1] != '\0' )
{
    printf( "bad file size\n" );
    exit( 1 );
}
total_bytes = atoi( buffer );
```

**One final note**
[while(!feof(fp))-is-always-wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432517/3386109)